# SOLR relevance seems tied heavily to length of document indexed

Tags: search, solr

We have a lot of documents in SOLR and a certain type of them tend to score too highly in results (it appears mainly due them generally being quite short in content). So if I search for a name it will always return a load of short documents before anything longer.

How can I weight results so that the length of the document is taken more into account when ranking for relevance?

If it helps (as a cludge) we have a flag set on the documents this generally applies to, so if it is possible to boost all documents who don't have this flag set that would be a temporary option for us.

Comment: Have you looked at [Solr Relevancy FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ) - you may be able to get some hints from there. Its a bit difficult to give an answer without actually looking at the documents.

Comment: I have been reading that for some time now :)

Comment: I generally use `debugQuery=on` in my Solr request to see the score, it gives out good amount of detail, but generally gives a good sense of why a document is ranked such.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the lengthNorm in scoring.  Longer documents with the same matching terms receive a somewhat lower score than short documents.  See [TFIDFSimilarity](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html)'s documentation (scroll down to "`6. norm(t,d)`"), as well as in [Solr documentation here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_are_documents_scored).

This tends to work well for full-text searching applications.  The idea being that the document with the higher proportion of it's content matching the query is more relevant to the query.

For instance, if I search wikipedia article titles for the term Monkey, relevance of articles found might be:

- [Monkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey) - Precise match, it would be reasonable to assume this is what I was looking for
- [Spider Monkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider_Monkey) - A well-known type of monkey, still quite relevant
- [Monkey: Journey to the West](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey%3a_Journey_to_the_West) - A stage play featuring a main character who is a monkey.  Likely less relevant.
- [African green monkey lymphotropic polyomavirus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_green_monkey_lymphotropic_polyomavirus) - A human tumor virus.  Relevance to query limited.

If it's really necessary, this can be overridden in a custom [DefaultSimilarity](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/DefaultSimilarity.html).  And overriding computeNorm(state,norm) to simply `return state.getBoost();`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the source of [DefaultSimilarity](http://fossies.org/dox/apache-solr-4.0.0-src/DefaultSimilarity_8java_source.html) for 4.0

```
@Override
public void computeNorm(FieldInvertState state, Norm norm) {
    final int numTerms;
    if (discountOverlaps)
        numTerms = state.getLength() - state.getNumOverlap();
    else
        numTerms = state.getLength();
    norm.setByte(encodeNormValue(state.getBoost() * ((float) (1.0 / Math.sqrt(numTerms)))));
}
```

So the numTerms have an adverse impact on the scoring.
You can create a Custom class overriding the behaviour

1. numTerms equal to 1
2. Change the Calculation to increase the score on longer documents rather the inverse now
3. Remove the calculation `((float) (1.0 / Math.sqrt(numTerms)))` to eliminate lengthNorm effect.